# How to continue execution when Assertion is failed

Tags: java, testng, selenium-rc, assertion, verify

I am using Selenium RC using Java with eclipse and TestNG framework. I have the following code snippet:

```
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please enter Email ID"));
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please enter Password"));
```

First assertion was failed and execution was stopped. But I want to continue the further snippet of code.

Comment: So if you don't want a failure in the first assertion to stop your program: what effect **should** it have, then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selenium IDE uses verify to perform a soft assertion, meaning that the test will continue even if the check fails and either report the failures at the end of the test or on the event of a hard assertion.

With TestNG it is possible to have these soft assertions by using custom test listeners. I have documented how to do this on my blog: http://davehunt.co.uk/2009/10/08/using-soft-assertions-in-testng.html

Basically, you need to create your own `verify*` methods, in these you can catch assertion failures and add them to a map. Then in a custom `afterInvocation` listener you can set the test to failed if the map is not empty.

Comment: Dave, i was looking for same thing but your blog link is not working. Can you please give me some other link for above answer.

Comment: @Dave Is the blog no longer available?

Comment: This answer is now outdated.

Comment: Dave Hunt: the blog is Not Found. Why is it inactive?

Comment: The blog was migrated, this article is now available at http://davehunt.co.uk/2009/10/08/using-soft-assertions-in-testng.html but note that this article is now 8 years old and likely out of date.

Answer (score 28):

I suggest you to use soft assertions, which are provided in TestNg natively

```
package automation.tests;

import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class MyTest {
  private Assertion hardAssert = new Assertion();
  private SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
}

@Test
public void testForSoftAssertionFailure() {
  softAssert.assertTrue(false);
  softAssert.assertEquals(1, 2);
  softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

Source: http://rameshbaskar.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/soft-assertions-using-testng/

Comment: This answer is more relevant to OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding again one of the easiest ways to continue on assertion failure. This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168684/how-to-not-stop-execution-after-assertion-fails).

```
try{
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
        }catch(AssertionError e)
        {
            System.out.println("Assertion error. ");
        }

        System.out.println("Test Completed.");
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your assertions to verifications:

```
verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please enter Email ID"));
verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please enter Password"));
```

Comment: Where is the `verifyTrue` method defined?

Answer (score 1):

Once an assertion fails, execution should stop, that's the point of using them.

You can declare an assertion that tests both things, but then you're testing two things at once. Better to fix the cause of the first failure, then move on to the second assertion.

Comment: Ofc, that test should succeed in 100% and fail othervise, but this particular functionality of "soft assertions" is usefull when you want to see all failed assertions (eg. failed assertions for 4 of 12 field values of tested object) in single test case, and not to break up after first one.