# How to use verifyText for comparing two strings?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

As we know, assert continues the execution but verify stops the execution the moment the script fails.
e.g suppose two string abc, abd xyz

i want to verify the two strings. How to verify them without using Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);

Can anyone please guide me for the same?

Comment: From my understanding of your question this issue was answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the 2 strings by creating a method and using if else to compare them.
In your example instead of assert this can be done

```
 public void compareMethod()
 {
    string expected = "abc";
    string actual = "xyz";
    if(expected == actual) 
       {
         //do steps required
       } 
    else
       {
       }
 }
```

Comment: if(expected == actual) is wrong. It compares object not the value. Use equals() method.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi It looks like C# code (`string` instead of `String`). C# allows string comparation with `==`

Answer (score 0):

If you have already stored strings and want to verifyText using Selenium WebDriver then the following code will surely help..

```
 if("expected String".equals("actual string"))
   {
      System.out.println("String matches ");
   }
 else
  {
      System.out.println("String does not match ");
  }
```

Try this