# TestNG : Is any way where I can mark test fail in TestNG report and continue same test..

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is any way where I can mark test fail in TestNG report and continue same test..
Problem with me that Test would not execute when test Case fail by using Assert.assertEquals(acutalResult,ExpectedResult). I have tried with try catch block but problem is still exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to continue execution when Assertion is failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed)

Answer (score 0):

An assert failure throws an AssertionError.  Its an Error and not an Exception.  You might have tried to capture an Exception in your catch and hence, it would not have worked.  What you need is soft assertions.  Try searching for soft assertions and you can get other implementation approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add try/catch for each assert seperately. Define a variable and increment if there is any failure. And finally fail the test case if it is more than 0.

```
try{
 //assertion cod
}catch(AssertionError ae){
 Reporter.log(Print failure to report);
 errorCounter++;
}

if(errorCounter > 0){
 fail(message);
}
```

Comment: i am using this but fail method shows pass in the report but i want to show fail method in Result section.

Comment: Can you tell the structure of your tests? Is it one test class or class with multiple methods? How do you specify that in testng xml?

Comment: it is one test class with only one method. and 3 assert at the end of method. 
Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, Actualtooltip);
Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult1, Actualtooltip1);
Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult1, Actualtooltip1);
Problem is if 1st fail other two doesn't work. I want to run these all and should show failed test in the testNG report.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG will create a xml file, '**testng-failed.xml**' after your test failure; It contains all the failed test Methods. It can be used to re-run your Failed tests manually or automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on "Soft Assertion vs Hard Assertion". Just google it. There is plenty information on how to do that.

A "soft assertion" allows you to to assert a (partial) test result without breaking the testing flow. You basically log your result (see example below) what ever it may look like and veryify it later after the test has finished by either raising a failure manually or assert the "log" (Check if failures avalable: If not - pass, if with failures - set fail)

Have a look at this resource: [Exampl](http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/)