# How to Fail a Test Case for 1 particular data and continue executing the same script in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assert, testng-dataprovider

I have a test script which is to be run for "n" number of data, I'm Doing that using `@DataProvider`, Now my problem is when i use `"Assert"` to fail the test case when test fails for 1 particular data, then execution of whole Test Script stops. I want it to keep executing even when it fails for 1 data. How can i do it ? can anybody help? thanks !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to continue execution when Assertion is failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed)

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you'll need to use a soft Assertion which usually records the failure and continue execution although i personally think that when a failure occur test should stop and shouldn't go further however this depends on how independent and simple your tests are.

See links below to help you with Soft Assertions

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.java
https://rameshbaskar.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/soft-assertions-using-testng/