# Running other test steps in TestNG after Assertion failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi i have a scenario where i have a  widget in that widget if the text appears "PROBLEM Loading Data" i ll refresh the page for 3 times even after the text appears means  i have to fail that step and going forward i have to verify the other text as well in that widget

But, if i use try and catch at the end it showing both as passed
Default suite

Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

But ideally i am looking for Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0 and rest of the steps to execute in that case

My script i tried with soft and hard assertions

i tried by removing the try catch but next steps are not executing

```
        case "CHECKWIDGET":
         int Pagerefresh=1;
         try{

        String s=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType))).getText();
        if(s.contains("Problem Loading Data")){
         for(Pagerefresh=1;Pagerefresh<=3;Pagerefresh++){
          Thread.sleep(7000);
          driver.navigate().refresh();
        System.out.println("refreshed time"+Pagerefresh);
        if(Pagerefresh==3){
            singleton.getFailedLogger().fatal("Error:Problem Loading Data In "+value+" Widget");
            Assert.assertTrue(s.contains("Problem Loading Data"));
          }   
         }
        }
         }     
         catch(AssertionError | NullPointerException e){
            Assert.fail();
        }
        try{
            String s=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType))).getText();
        if(s.contains(value)){
        singleton.getLogger().debug(passlog);
        }else{
            singleton.getFailedLogger().fatal(faillog);
        }
        }
        catch(AssertionError | NullPointerException e){
            singleton.getFailedLogger().fatal(faillog);
        }

        break;
```

please help,

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to continue, it doesn't work.  Just fix the problems.  Strategies around making tests continue after failures are usually a symptom of tests that are flaky.  If you tests are regularly failing they are either no good, or the software you are testing is no good.

Comment: yes completely agree with u this is a new product which they are developing from scratch  sometimes data would not be loading bcoz of the some internal issues that time problem loading data turns up on the page i have to refresh it again and again so i had to write a script like this.

Comment: Surely the data not loading due to internal issues is a failure that needs to be fixed.  Why would you not want to fail if this is the case?

Comment: yes it is a failure.. but there are some other texts too which i wanted to verify but its coming out of the case statement if i don't use try and catch i ll modify and fail it. as it will be failing always. i just wanted to know is there any way for such problems so posted this question. thanks for ur time

Comment: So if you want it to still error, you are going to need to throw an Exception.  That means you are going to need to track that you have caught an error, then you will need to throw an exception at the end.  The simplest solution would probably be to set a boolean flag that becomes true whenever an exception is caught and then throws an Exception at the end if it is true.

Comment: oh ok sure i ll try this out i ll throw an exception at the end of the method. sound good thanks ur 'http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/' is not opening i would love to sucribe for ur channel for any selenium updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90788/discussion-between-chaitanya-pujari-and-ardesco).

Comment: You should have a look into `dependsOnMethod`, "retry analyzer" and maybe "SoftAssert" features from TestNG.

Comment: Look like I need to recycle and AWS instance, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed/5405927#5405927

Answer (score 1):

what you need is soft assertion.

Soft Assertions

Tests don’t stop running even if an assertion condition fails, but the test itself is marked as a failed test to indicate the right result.

Take a [look](https://rameshbaskar.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/soft-assertions-using-testng/)