# Checking Soft Assertions in @AfterMethod

Tags: testng

I want to check my Soft Assertions in TestNG using `@AfterMethod`. I want to do something like this:

```
SoftAssert sa;

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void beforeMethod() {
    sa = new SoftAssert();
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    sa.assertTrue(false);
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    sa.assertTrue(false);
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterMethod() {
    sa.assertAll();
}
```

The problem is that TestNG marks this as 1 test passed, 1 configuration failed:

> Default test 
>   Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 
>       Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 1

[image]

How can I tell TestNG that this test failed? I want to use the `@AfterMethod` so I don't have to worry about false positives if I forget to put `sa.assertAll()` at the end of the test.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: So it shows in the test results as a test failure and not configuration failure

Comment: Ok, but your a not supposed to do that in that way. Assertions should be part of the @Test method. @Before/After are there for common test setup and/or test cleanup.

Comment: but that is prone to error if you do soft assertions and then forget to call the assertAll method

Comment: In this case, don't use SoftAssert and use Assert instead ;)

Comment: yes, but sometimes you want to use soft asserts instead

Comment: So, don't forget to call `assertAll` ;)

Comment: smartass... I am trying to take out that manual step, because I have people less experienced using the framework. If you're not going to provide a solution, there's no need to comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94977/discussion-between-zmorris-and-juherr).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed/5405927#5405927

Comment: @Stormy This is not a duplicate of the link above... read the question carefully to understand the problem first. My question was about the execution order of the TestNG annotations working together with the soft assert, not about the general use of soft assert vs hard assert.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
    try {
        sa.assertAll();
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        result.setStatus(FAILURE);
        result.setThrowable(t);
    }
}
```