# Selenium - TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

This question was asked in an interview. Lets say there is a class with 4 test methods, with priorities given properly.
While running the test cases, 3rd test case is getting failed. So, how to make sure that the 4th Test case has been run?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Soft Assertions in testNG to do that. Have a look [here](https://rameshbaskar.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/soft-assertions-using-testng/) how this can be utilized.

And [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html) is the SoftAssert class

Also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed) for other methods to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the 4th Test case is always executed you have to set the **`alwaysRun`** argument to **`true`** along with the **`TestNG annotation`** as follows:

```
@Test(priority=4)(alwaysRun=true)
void pkg3() 
{
    System.out.println("pkg3");
}
```

Comment: `alwaysRun` is not going to work here because there is no dependencies between the tests. Quoting the javadocs for the `alwaysRun` attribute `If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends on a method that failed.  This attribute will be ignored if this test doesn't depend on any method or group.`. `priority` is not a `hard dependency` (like `dependsOnMethods` (or) `dependsOnGroups`) and so its not controlled/affected by `alwaysRun`