# How to Fail TestNG test case and continue running test cases

Tags: testng

If one Assert fails or I manually fail test cases using Assert.Fail(); function it will raise an exception and the rest of the test cases will not run. Hoe do I force execution of the entire test suite if one or more Asserts are failing.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to continue execution when Assertion is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402412/how-to-continue-execution-when-assertion-is-failed)

Answer (score 1):

> If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends
>   on a method that failed.

@Test(alwaysRun=true)